# Convert data frame columns to one sound

Tags: r

I'm interested in converting my data into a sound. My data is in a dataframe. Each column represents the relative amplitude of sound at a specific frequency. Each row is a sample. Samples are recorded at a fixed sample rate. I've figured out how to get a sound out using the [seewave package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/seewave/index.html), but not at the specific frequencies that I want.

Example:

```
library(seewave)

# some dummy data, 3 columns
set.seed(7)
df <- data.frame(f1=rnorm(600,30,5), f2=rnorm(600,40,10), 3=rnorm(600,30,10))
df[df<0] <- 0

mat <- as.matrix(df)
mat <- t(mat) +0i # istft() only works with complex numbers
sr <- 1000 # sample rate in Hz
freqs <- c(500, 2000, 10000) # desired frequencies of output sounds for each column

sound <- istft(mat,f=sr,ovlp=50,wl=256,output = "Wave") # creates a sound 
listen(sound)
```

`istft` assumes:

> "a complex matrix resulting of a short-term Fourier transform".

My `mat` object is obviously not in the right format, so I'm not sure what the output actually is. I can't figure out how to force each column from the dataframe to the frequencies stored in freqs.

Any ideas would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Actually your code runs but there is a warning saying

> 1: In xprim * win :
>    longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

To resolve this, your `mat` has to have a number of rows that is divisible by 2 and is smaller than your FFT window length (`wl`):

```
library(seewave)

# some dummy data, 3 columns
set.seed(7)
N = 128
df <- data.frame(f1=rnorm(N,30,5), f2=rnorm(N,40,10), f3=rnorm(N,30,10))
df[df<0] <- 0

mat <- as.matrix(df)
#no need to transpose
mat <- mat + 0i # istft() only works with complex numbers

sr <- 1000 # sample rate in Hz
freqs <- c(500, 2000, 10000) # desired frequencies of output sounds for each column

sound <- istft(mat, f=sr, ovlp=50, wl=256, output = "Wave") # creates a sound 
listen(sound)
```

The above code will not give you that warning. You can step through the `istft` code for the example provided in `?istft` and for your code to see what is causing the warning.

Comment: Nice catch. I've figured out my problem and will post an answeer

Answer (score 1):

So I managed to do this by synthesising waves using the synth() function. This works through each column of the dataframe and creates an amplitude modulated signal on a carrier frequency. Then, results from all columns are added together.

```
library(seewave)
library(tuneR)

nsamps <- 600 # number of samples to create
sf <- 10 # sampling frequency of the data in Hz
fout <- 22000 # Sample frequency of output sound (Hz)
dout <- 10 # length of output sound file (seconds)

# some dummy amplitude data, 3 columns
df <- data.frame(f1 = sin((1:nsamps)/180*pi)+1, f2 = sin((1:nsamps)/180*pi + pi)+1, f3 = sin((1:nsamps)/90*pi)+1)

mat <- as.matrix(df)
freqs <- seq(100, 1000, length.out = ncol(mat)) # Carrier frequencies for each data column (Hz)

syn <- 0 # this is the synthesised wave
atemp <- seq(from=1, to=nrow(mat), length.out = fout*dout) # new times
for(ii in 1:ncol(mat)){ # for each data column
  scale_data <- (mat[,ii] - min(mat[,ii]))/diff(range(mat[,ii])) # scale each column between 0 and 1, comment out for absolute amplitudes across all columns
  amp <- approx(x = 1:nrow(mat), y = scale_data, xout = atemp)$y # sample the amplitude data onto the new times
  syn <- syn + synth(f = fout, d = dout, cf = freqs[ii], output = 'wave', a = amp) # build up the total synth wave

}

wave <- Wave(left = syn, samp.rate=fout, bit=16) # create a wave class
listen(wave) # listen to the sound
```

Here is the code to create a spectrogram plot:

```
t_win <- 0.5 # window length for spectrogram (s)
n_win <- t_win/(nsamps/sf/dout)*fout # calculate the window length in samples
spectro(wave, f=fout, flim = c(0,1.1), wl = n_win, ovlp = 75) # plot the spectrogram
```

[image]